# Intuitive explanation of the bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: regression, variance, bias, intuition, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am looking for an intuitive explanation of the bias-variance tradeoff, both in general and specifically in the context of linear regression.

Comment: There is another discussion relevant to these topics here: [what-problem-do-shrinkage-methods-solve](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20295/).

Comment: http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Imagine some 2D data--let's say height versus weight for students at a high school--plotted on a pair of axes.

Now suppose you fit a straight line through it. This line, which of course represents a set of predicted values, has zero statistical variance. But the bias is (probably) high--i.e., it doesn't fit the data very well.

Next, suppose you model the data with a high-degree polynomial spline. You're not satisfied with the fit, so you increase the polynomial degree until the fit improves (and it will, to arbitrary precision, in fact). Now you have a situation with bias that tends to zero, but the variance is very high.

Note that the bias-variance trade-off doesn't describe a proportional relationship--i.e., if you plot bias versus variance you won't necessarily see a straight line through the origin with slope -1. In the polynomial spline example above, reducing the degree almost certainly increases the variance much less than it decreases the bias.

The bias-variance tradeoff is also embedded in the sum-of-squares error function. Below, I have rewritten (but not altered) the usual form of this equation to emphasize this:

$$
E\left(\left(y - \dot{f}(x)\right)^2\right) = \sigma^2 + \left[f(x) - \frac{1}{\kappa}\sum_{i=0}^nf(x_n)\right]^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{\kappa}
$$

On the right-hand side, there are three terms: the first of these is just the irreducible error (the variance in the data itself); this is beyond our control so ignore it. The *second* term is the **square of the bias**; and the *third* is the **variance**. It's easy to see that as one goes up the other goes down--they can't both vary together in the same direction. Put another way, you can think of least-squares regression as (implicitly) finding the optimal combination of bias and variance from among candidate models.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the equation; I can't find any way to justify it. Even a basic units analysis identifies problems. Suppose $y$ is measured in parsecs and $x$ in drams, for example, so that $f$ and its estimator (is that what the little dot over the $f$ means?) are also in parsecs. Then the lhs and $\sigma^2$ are squared parsecs; the middle term on the rhs is the square of a difference between a parsec ($f(x)$) and parsecs per dram (due to the division by $x$); and the last term on the rhs is squared parsecs per dram. It's not valid to add any of these terms to one another!

Comment: the equation's fine (the little greek letters in the numerator are *not* 'x' but 'kappa'). Try this: begin w/ a formula for SSE that you are comfortable with and just a few steps will get you to the one above.

Comment: What is 'kappa' in this context?

Comment: A simpler example: y=a+b*x+e(rror).  If I fit a constant to this, bias = b*x and variance = var(e) + the variance of my estimate of a around the true value.  If I add a term b*x to the model, bias is zero everywhere, but now variance includes the effects of the error of my estimate of b as well as of a and the variance of e, so will be higher than in the first case.  So there's a tradeoff between decreased bias, obtained by adding terms to the model that ought to be there, and increased variance, obtained by having to estimate those terms and, possibly, adding irrelevant ones.

Comment: @jbowman, would it make sense to average the two models to shrink b ?
Or take the average of a linear-only fit and a quadratic fit, 
([a0 a1 0] + [b0 b1 b2]) / 2,
in order to damp the quadratic term to reduce overshoot ?

Comment: Dont think "reducing the degree almost certainly increases the variance much less than it decreases the bias." is right. Reducing the degree won't increase the variance and it will increase the bias

Answer (score 27):

Let's say you are considering catastrophic health insurance, and there is a 1% probability of getting sick which would cost 1 million dollars.  The expected cost of getting sick is thus 10,000 dollars. The insurance company, wanting to make a profit, will charge you 15,000 for the policy.

Buying the policy gives an expected cost to you of 15,000, which has a variance of 0 but can be thought of as biased since it is 5,000 more than the real expected cost of getting sick.

Not buying the policy gives an expected cost of 10,000, which is unbiased since it is equal to the true expected cost of getting sick, but has a very high variance.
The tradeoff here is between an approach that is consistently wrong but never by much and an approach that is correct on average but is more variable.

Answer (score 25):

I highly recommend having a look at [Caltech ML course by Yaser Abu-Mostafa, Lecture 8 (Bias-Variance Tradeoff)](http://work.caltech.edu/lectures.html#lectures) . Here are the outlines:

Say you are trying to learn the sine function:

[image]

Our training set consists of only 2 data points.

Let's try to do it with two models, $h_0(x)=b$ and $h_1(x)=ax+b$:

For $h_0(x)=b$, when we try with many different training sets (i.e. we repeatedly select 2 data points and perform the learning on them), we obtain (left graph represents all the learnt models, right graph represent their mean g and their variance (grey area)):

[image]

For $h_1(x)=ax+b$, when we try with many different training sets, we obtain:

[image]

If we compare the learnt model with $h_0$ and $h_1$, we can see that $h_0$ yields more simple models than $h_1$, hence a lower **variance** when we consider all the models learnt with $h_0$, but the best model g (in red on the graph) learnt with $h_1$ is better than the best model learnt g with $h_0$, hence a lower **bias** with $h_1$:

[image]

---

If you look at the evolution of the cost function with respect to the size of the training set (figures from [Coursera - Machine Learning by Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml)):

High bias:

[image]

High variance:

[image]

Comment: +1, very elaborative. Take $h_1$ as the example, We have drawn many different samples $D_i$, each with 2 points, so we trained many models each with different model parameter estimate $(\hat a_i,\hat b_i)$, right? And for a specific input $x_0$, different $(\hat a_i,\hat b_i)$ gives different prediction $\hat y_0$, so the predicted target value $\hat y_0$ is a random variable varying with the model parameter estimate $(\hat a,\hat b)$. And the bias and variance in your fig are computed for each $x$'s predicted $\hat y$, right? Am I correct?

Comment: your sine function is inverted  X-P

Comment: This is confusing b/c you seem to be referring to plots that aren't there (maybe the "alt text"s).

Comment: @gung fixed, thanks for pointing it out. [ImageShack shut down free accounts and deleting images](http://budgetlightforum.com/node/44525). And Stack Exchange failed to take appropriate measures. Related: [Ban ImageShack images because they are reusing old URLs for advertising](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/178179) (please support the ban) ; [What is the easiest way for me to download all my questions+answers across all Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209317/178179) (I am glad I had a backup; please push StackExchange to provide better tools to back up content)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the videos link, It explain well what I was looking for, can now understand your answer

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt do you recall how exactly those bias and variance calculations were done in the sine example? It's a regression problem and yet, the "bias" and "variance" are calculated as a **single number** each across **fittings** (_and_ across $x$?). In other words, how are they calculated? What's the formula they used? to get those precise bias and variance numbers? In a sense, I'm asking this [exact question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469384/bias-variance-decomposition-expectations-over-what). I landed here trying to precisely answer that question.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I think g bar ist not the best model but the average of all models of the respective class.

Answer (score 25):

First, lets understand the meaning of bias and variance:

[image: Understanding bias and Variance]

Imagine the center of the red bulls' eye region is the true mean value of our target random variable which we are trying to predict. Every time we take a sample set of observations and predict the value of this variable we plot a blue dot. We predicted correctly if the blue dot falls inside the red region. *Bias* is the measure of how far off are the predicted blue dots from the center of the red region (the true mean). Intuitively bias is quantification of error.
Variance is how scattered are our predictions.

The top left is the ideal condition but it is hard to achieve in practice, and the bottom right is the worst-case scenario which is easy to achieve in practice (usually the starting condition for randomly initialized models).
Our goal is to go from the bottom right (high bias high variance) situation to the top left situation (low variance low bias).

But the problem here is:
Unfortunately, achieving the lowest variance and lowest bias simulatneously is hard. (Why so? That's a deeper question).
When we try to decrease one of this parameter (either bias or variance), the other parameter increases.

Now the trade-off here is:

There is a sweet spot somewhere in between which produces the least prediction error in the long run.

[image: The trade-off between Bias and Variance]

These pictures are taken from http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html . Checkout the explanations with linear regression and K-nearest neighbors for more details

Comment: the first figure looks more like precision vs accuracy?

Answer (score 18):

> The basic idea is that too simple a model will underfit (high bias)
> while too complex a model will overfit (high variance) and that bias
> and variance trade off as model complexity is varied.

(Neal, 2019)

However, while bias-variance tradeoff seems to hold for some simple algorithms like linear regression, or $k$-NN, **it's not that simple**. I'll briefly summarize some of the points made in [this blog entry](https://www.bradyneal.com/bias-variance-tradeoff-textbooks-update), by Neal (2019), and Neal et al (2018).

There's growing body of evidence that this is not generally true and in some machine learning algorithms we observe, so called, *double descent* phenomenon. There are some preliminary evidence that for random forests, gradient boosting algorithms, and neural networks this might not be the case. It was observed that wider networks (more neurons) generalize better. Moreover, as discussed by Belkin et al (2019), for overparametrized neural networks and random forests, the bias-variance curve hits certain threshold, where the model overfits, and then, as the number of parameters grows beyond the number of datapoints, the test error starts falling again with growing model complexity (see figure from the paper reproduced below).

[image]

Nice example for this was given by Neal (2019), and Neal et al (2018), using simple, single layer, dense neural network, trained with stochastic gradient descent on the subset of 100 samples from MNIST. Nonetheless that the number of parameters starts exceeding the number of samples, we do not see tradeoff in terms of decrease of test set performance.

[image]

Belkin et al (2019) give even more striking example using random forest.

[image]

As discussed by Neal (2019), lack of bias-variance tradeoff for neural networks was even visible in the widely cited paper by Geman et al (1992) who did the first empirical study on this topic and popularized it. Moreover, when discussing bias-variance tradeoff, it is often shown how squared error can be decomposed into bias and variance, no matter that it does not directly apply to other error metrics, and the fact that you can decompose it *does not* prove anyhow that there is a tradeoff.

All this shows that we do not yet have good understanding of how and why some of the modern machine learning algorithms work, and some of our commonly held intuitions may be misleading.

---

Belkin, M., Hsub, D., Maa, S., & Mandala, S. (2019). [Reconciling modern machine learning practice and the bias-variance trade-off.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11118) stat, 1050, 10.
Neal, B. (2019). [On the Bias-Variance Tradeoff: Textbooks Need an Update.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08286) arXiv preprint arXiv:1912.08286.
Neal, B., Mittal, S., Baratin, A., Tantia, V., Scicluna, M., Lacoste-Julien, S., & Mitliagkas, I. (2018). [A modern take on the bias-variance tradeoff in neural networks.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08591) arXiv preprint arXiv:1810.08591.

Comment: Hi @Tim, are you saying here that the simple experiments of Neal et al. contradict the findings in Belkin et al.? (if I understand your explanation correctly)

Comment: @KirkWalla no, both describe similar phenomen.

Comment: It's great that this page includes the modern understanding of the B-V tradeoff!

Comment: I probably need to read the paper, but I find that random forest example a bit suspicious. It seem like on the right of the graph, the number of *trees* in the forest start to increase. I would not say this increases the complexity of the model, the tress are averaged, so this is reducing the variance while keeping the bias constant. To the extent that "complexity" is understood as "model variance", this seems to make exactly the opposite point than intended.

Comment: Are there any regularisations on these models (i.e. dropout for the deep learning experiments)?

Comment: @TommyLees no, I recommend you the papers for the details. The point of this research was to show what happens when we increase the number of parameters not decrease (regularization).

Comment: Adding parameters might effectively increase the degree of (implicit) regularisation and reduce the variance. This also happens in linear models ([Is ridge regression useless in high dimensions (n≪p)? How can OLS fail to overfit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328630/))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple explanation. Imagine you have a scatter plot of points {x_i,y_i} that were sampled from some distribution. You want to fit some model to it. You can choose a linear curve or a higher order polynomial curve or something else. Whatever you choose is going to be applied to predict new y values for a set of {x_i} points. Let's call these the validation set. Let's assume that you also know their true {y_i} values and we are using these just to test out model.

The predicted values are going to be different from the real values. We can measure the properties of their differences. Let's just consider a single validation point. Call it x_v and choose some model. Let's make a set of predictions for that one validation point by using say 100 different random samples for training the model. So we are going to get 100 y values. The difference between the mean of those values and the true value is called the bias. The variance of the distribution is the variance.

Depending on what model we use we can trade off between these two. Let's consider the two extremes. The lowest variance model is one where completely ignore the data. Let's say we simply predict 42 for every x. That model has zero variance across different training samples at every point. However it is clearly biased. The bias is simply 42-y_v.

One the other extreme we can choose a model which overfits as much as possible. For example fit a 100 degree polynomial to 100 data points. Or alternatively, linearly interpolate between nearest neighbors. This has low bias. Why? Because for any random sample the neighboring points to x_v will fluctuate widely but they will interpolate higher just about as often as they will interpolate low. So on average across the samples, they will cancel out and the bias will therefore be very low unless the true curve has lots of high frequency variation.

Hoever these overfit models have large variance across the random samples because they are not smoothing the data. The interpolation model just uses two data points to predict the intermediate one and these therefore create a lot of noise.

Note that the bias is measured at a single point. It doesn't matter if it is positive or negative. It is still a bias at any given x. The biases averaged over all the x values will probably be small but that doesn't make it unbiased.

One more example. Say you are trying to predict the temperature at set of locations in the US at some time. Let's assume you have 10,000 training points. Again, you can get a low variance model by doing something simple by just returning the average. But this will be biased low in the state of Florida and biased high in the state of Alaska. You'd be better if you used the average for each state. But even then, you will be biased high in the winter and low in the summer. So now you include the month in your model. But you're still going to be biased low in Death Valley and high on Mt Shasta. So now you go to the zip code level of granularity. But eventually if you keep doing this to reduce the bias, you run out of data points. Maybe for a given zip code and month, you have only one data point. Clearly this is going to create lots of variance. So you see having a more complicated model lowers the bias at the expense of variance.

So you see there is a trade off. Models that are smoother have lower variance across training samples but don't capture the real shape of the curve as well. Models that are less smooth can better capture the curve but at the expense of being noisier. Somewhere in the middle is a Goldilocks model that makes an acceptable tradeoff between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if model building task could be repeated for different training datasets, i.e. we train a new model for different dataset every time(shown in the figure below). If we fix a test data point and evaluate model prediction on this point, the predictions will be varied due to randomness in the model generation process. From the below figure for this situation, P_1, P_2, …, P_n are different predictions and random too.
[image]

Let the mean of predictions be -

[image]

Bias Error is due to the difference between mean of these predictions and the correct value.
[image]

Variance Error is nothing but the variance in these predictions, i.e. how varied are these predictions.
[image]

This is the intuition behind bias and variance error.

For detailed explanation visit [right intuition behind bias variance tradeoff](https://machinelearningaptitude.com/topics/top-30/how-does-bias-and-variance-error-gets-introduced/)