# PCA vs ridge regression for multicollinearity?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

Orthogonalization via PCA and ridge regression are two common methods to account for multicollinearity for linear regression models.  When would you use one over the other?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework problem.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, and I was hoping for something other than whatever works best empirically.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but  I believe ridge regression encodes a multivariate mean-0 normal prior on the regression parameters ... assuming that you have reason to believe the regression parameters should follow this prior, is there any a priori reason to prefer one to the other?

Comment: @nan, you are correct - ridge regression is equivalent to a fitting a Guassian linear model with a Gaussian prior on the $\beta$s. Your second sentence confuses me though - if you have reason to believe that this is a good prior, then, of course, you do have an a priori reason to prefer ridge regression. Maybe I've misunderstood your query.

Comment: you may also find [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32471/how-can-you-handle-unstable-beta-estimates-in-linear-regression-with-high-mul) useful.

Answer (score 2):

When the cross-validated error of one method is lower than the other.  I would also look into [lasso regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#LASSO_method) and [elastic net regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization).