# Bias Variance tradeoff from a Bayesian perspective

Tags: regression, bayesian, variance, bias

I know the general question about bias variance has been asked before. I understand the frequentist approach and the concept of model selection and the impact of bias and variance on "accuracy" of a prediction.
I am looking for an intuitive explanation of bias and variance from a **Bayesian perspective.**

Comment: Do you want an explanation along the same lines as [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4287/44764) for Bayesian regression models, or are you looking for a discussion of bias and variance in sampling-theory regression models from a Bayesian perspective? Bias is automatically induced in the Bayesian approach just from using a prior, while the variance is decreased for the same reason.